Topology and local isometry, spinning cosmic string
Suppose one is given the spacetime $(M,g)$ where $M$ is a fixed differentiable manifold and $g$ is a Lorentzian metric whose local expression is:
$$g= -(dt + a \, d \phi)^2 + d\rho^2 + \kappa^2 \rho^2 \, d\phi^2 + dz^2 \ \text{where} \ \ a > 0$$
This is the spacetime of an infinite straight Spinning Cosmic String.
Suppose that the spacetime $(N,h)$ is locally isometric to the spacetime $(M,g)$.
Since there are distinct definitions of local isometry in the mathematical literature it's better to clarify one's definition explicitly:

Spcetime $(M,g)$ is locally isometric to $(N , h)$ if and only if each point $p \in M$ has an open neighborhood $U_p$ and an open neighborhood $V \subset N$ and a diffeomorphism $f: U_p \rightarrow V$ such that:
$$g \big |_{U_P}=f^*h \big|_{U_p}$$

The question is:
what can in general be extracted anout the differentiable manifold $N$ by a particular choice of $M$ inclusive of its differential structure?
This applies both to the differential structure over the manifold $N$ and its topology.

Downvote without comment unprofessional and disrespectful!

I suspect because this question seems like a more general version of your other question. Again, you haven't specified anything about the domain of the explicitly-given metric. Can we take $M$ to be literally $\mathbb{R}^4 \setminus \mathbb{R}^2$, or any open subset of this? A concrete question like "can we say anything about a maximal [adjectives] extension containing $\mathbb{R}^4 \setminus \mathbb{R}^2$ with this metric?" might go down better. The definition of local isometry is really not the problem here.

The question should have a general answer based on the symmetries of the spacetime and local isometry. In the sense of a general theorem regradless of the explicit form of the metric. That's actually pretty much a valid question as mathematical theorems are do not necessarily restrict themselves to a particular object! Nonetheless I have written the explicit local form of the metric so that if any further information is needed, one can freely extract it from the metric. Finally if you think you can put a step forward by analyzing only the case of $M= \mathbb{R}^4 - \mathbb{R}^2$go@DavidRoberts

This question is actually quite different, and I hope that readers will notice the difference. For example, if instead of the metric given, imagine that we take the de Sitter metric. So $N$ is required to be locally isometric to de Sitter space, and that is an interesting class of Lorentz manifolds, especially if we ask that $N$ not be isometric to a proper open set in any Lorentz manifold. To me, this is an interesting question.

@DavidRoberts This question is improved with respect to the previous one, and I don't think it deserves the downvotes. OP is just requiring a certain structure of the metric locally (in a chart), so $M$ can a priori be anything. It seems to me that the question  asks what can be deduced about $N$ (topologically, smoothly).

@BenMcKay: the question in your comment is certainly interesting, but I don't see any mention in the OP about any maximality condition. Without it I really don't see how anything meaningful can be said topologically.

Why nothing meaningful can be said? @WillieWong Take the Chern-Gauss-Bonnet theorem for the Riemannian manifolds, and since the Riemann, Ricci and scalar curvature are all preserved under local isomorphism, then the Euler characteristic is the same for $M$ and $M$. CGB can be generalised to the pseudo-riemannian case, but personally I'm not sure yet iff the Pseudo-Riemannian curvature and its contractions are preserved under the local isometry, though can be checked! this is the least one can say as a physics student! I guess you can find more with deeper mathematical insights!

@BastamTajik: curvature and contractions are invariant for local isometry in the pseudo-Riemannian case too// CGB is uninteresting for Lorentzian manifolds as every Lorentzian manifold admits a nowhere-vanishing vector field. (This fact is always true for any non-compact manifold, and for closed manifolds this is equivalent to vanishing Euler characteristic.)

@WillieWong What about other algebraic topological invariants? higher Chern/Pontryagin numbers and or maybe non-algebraic topological invariants and so on.

Let me just say that I am pessimistic; typically results of these type (in the Riemannian setting) demand some global information like completeness. And that is much stronger than the inextensibility requirement that Ben McKay suggested in his comment.

@BastamTajik if you have a local isometry, then the densities of the characteristic numbers will be locally the same but it's possible that when integrated they give you different results.  So you cannot conclude that $\chi (M) = \chi (N)$. The basic example is that of a covering map.

It seems as Willie Wang says, the Euler characteristic vanishes. But I was think about a comment regarding your previous answer. The topology of $M$ and $N$ can ne recovered by means of $g$ and $h$ separately as you said. So this much I can say that principally the topologies can be compared. What about Chern classes? Do you have any idea? Also thanks for the support. I hope the question is worth the attention. @Overflowian

@BastamTajik you should look at Chern-Weyl theory, the local densities associated to Chern forms can be expressed in terms of the curvature. But again local isometries will only allow to conclude something local in general. Note that if a manifold is flat  (as it seems to be your case of interest) then  the vanishing of the curvature implies the vanishing of the characteristic numbers.

@BastamTajik: If you don’t understand very basic things like why a tensor can’t be locally zero but globally nonzero, then I think you need to go learn basic manifold theory before you try to use MO.  I’m not trying to be rude, but from this and other things you have said it sounds like you don’t even have the prerequisites to understand the technical meanings of the terms in your questions or in the answers you would get here.  That is probably the source of all the conflicts you are having.

Sure. It was an absolutely stupid comment. @AndyPutman

@Overflowian ah, the thing I was missing is that it was everywhere locally isometric, not just in one place. Mea culpa!

@WillieWong I guess one needs a generalization of the Malament theorem for sets/manifolds whose causal structure is not even chronological. In other words, to fill in the blanks after removing "local isometry" one needs to know which bijective maps preserve a non-chronological causal structure. Maybe that's too much to ask already!

I think in your question, as currently formulated, the whole rotating cosmic string is a red herring.
If I interpret your notation correctly, $a$ and $\kappa$ are constants. And hence locally you can define $\psi = \kappa \phi$ and $s = t + a \phi$ to get that the metric is locally the same as $- ds^2 + d\rho^2 + \rho^2 d\psi^2 + dz^2$ which is just the Minkowski metric in disguise.
Therefore, for a manifold to be locally isometric to your rotating cosmic string is the same as asking for the manifold to be flat.
Absent other geometric conditions, I don't think there's anything meaningful that you can say about the topology of such a manifold. There's lots of "cut-and-glue" type operation you can do on subsets of Minkowski space to build such manifolds. In addition to the the operation that makes the rotating cosmic strong, you can also do something like "cut a closed three-dimensional disk from $\mathbb{R}^{1,3}$, double the manifold, and glue the two copies together by crossing the 'interiors'." You can use this to also glue on copies of the four torus and other stuff.
I think the key to the rotating cosmic string solution is precisely in its global structure that generates the closed time-like curves, but this is not something detectable at the local isometry level and so probably this means you are not asking the question you think you are asking.

Are these manifolds also known as flat Lorentzian $5$-manifolds? People certainly study complete flat Lorentzian manifolds. Without completeness it is harder to get off the ground even though some things can still be said topologically, e.g. one always has the developing map, so the universal cover of a flat Lorentzian manifold is stably parallelizable because it immerses into a Euclidean space of the same dimension.

@IgorBelegradek probably $4$-manifolds and not five. // Given the recent question of the OP on homotopy group, I am not sure whether looking at universal cover is useful. Remember that the starting point of this question is the spinning cosmic string, which is neither complete nor simply connected. // Feel free however to provide some references on results about complete flat Lorentzian manifolds; at least I would be interested to read more.

@IgorBelegradek: ah, I see I had a typo which confused the dimension for you. I fixed it. Thanks.

I am not an expert, but e.g. "Complete Flat Affine And Lorentzian Manifolds" by Charette, Drumm, Goldman, https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2598958_Complete_Flat_Affine_And_Lorentzian_Manifolds, and  Goldman and Kamishima, "The fundamental group of a compact flat Lorentz space form is virtually polycyclic" J. Differential Geom (1984) or https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/jdanciger/pdfs/RNC-slides.pdf.

Much of the subject focuses on 3d Margulis spacetimes as e.g. in https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.2240. Are these the same flat Lorenzian manifolds you are talking about?

Margulis spacetimes are "smaller"; they are quotients of Minkowski space by some group action, so certainly give rise to flat Lorentzian manifolds. The construction I mentioned with cutting-and-gluing is a bit like what you do to build (noncompact) Riemann surfaces. // Thanks for the references from 2-up.

@WillieWong To be honest I feel quite desparate. Since there's no easy mathematical way I can express what I mean. Vaugely I need at least two non-diffeomorphic manifolds that the metric tensor is locally that of the spinning Cosmic String. Or the diffeomorphic classes of such possible choices. One might say this is too general of a question. But even fixing the topology and changing only the differential structure would of great interest.

@BastamTajik: I don't think you understood my answer. The condition that your manifold is flat allows fairly wild topologies. Certainly Minkowski space and the cosmic string spacetime are locally isometric but do not admit global diffeomorphisms. The point of my answer is that there's enough freedom topologically that it is hard to say anything universal about all of them.
